# Optimization of MySQL query have millions of records

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

OBJECTIVE: Need query to count all "distinct" leads outside of current company that do not exist in current company. The query needs to account for millions of records between multiple tables (lead_details, domains, company)

```
EXAMPLE: 
  company 1 -> domain 1 -> lead 1 lead_details records exists.
  company 2 -> domain 2 -> lead 1 lead_details records exists.  
  company 2 -> domain 2 -> lead 2 lead_details records exists. 
  company 3 -> domain 3 -> lead 2 lead_details records exists. 
  company 3 -> domain 3 -> lead 3 lead_details records exists.
```

RESULT: If I run the query for the data above on company 1, the result should be a count of (2) since lead 2 & lead 3 is unique and does not exist in company 1

```
domain_id domain_name company_id company_name lead_id lead_count
    "2"         "D2"        "2"       "C2"        "2"      "2"
    "3"         "D3"        "3"       "C3"        "3"      "1"
```

Here is my Query, Please let me know if anyone has any better suggestion.

```
SELECT al.*
FROM (
    SELECT 
    d.id AS domain_id, 
    d.name AS domain_name, 
    c.id AS company_id, 
    c.name AS company_name, 
    ld.lead_id, 
    count(ld.lead_id) as lead_count 
    FROM domains d 
    INNER JOIN company c
    ON (c.id = d.company_id AND c.id != 1)
    INNER JOIN lead_details ld 
    ON (ld.domain_id = d.id)
    GROUP BY ld.lead_id
) al 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ld.lead_id FROM domains d 
    INNER JOIN company c
    ON (c.id = d.company_id AND c.id = 1)
    INNER JOIN lead_details ld 
    ON (ld.domain_id = d.id)
) ccl
ON al.lead_id = ccl.lead_id 
WHERE ccl.lead_id IS NULL;
```

I have almost million rows, so need to figure out better solution..

Comment: Please add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE domains` to your question, and the same for `company` and `lead_details` tables. That will allow us to see existing indexes, as well as verifying the data types.

Answer (score 0):

**Plan A**

The pattern

```
FROM ( SELECT ... )
JOIN ( SELECT ... ) ON ...
```

is inefficient, especially in older versions of MySQL.  This is because neither of the subqueries has any indexes, so (in older versions) a repeated full table scan is needed of one of the subqueries.

The better method is to try to reformulate as

```
FROM t1 ...
JOIN t2 ... ON ...
JOIN t3 ... ON ...
LEFT JOIN t4 ... ON ...
LEFT JOIN t5 ... ON ...
```

**Plan B**

This is closer to what you have...

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ccl
        ( INDEX(lead_id) )
    SELECT ... -- the stuff that is after LEFT JOIN
```

Then replace that subquery with just `ccl`.  This provides the index that is missing from the original query.

**Plan C**

Summary Table.  (This may or may not be practical for your query, since you are looking *distinct* and *do not exist*.)  Every month (or week or whatever) calculate subtotals for the last month and store it into another table.  Then the query against this other table will be much faster.